# Java getResourceAsStream is loading a previous version of desired file but not the most recently created file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-threads

Hi I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file), to load an image I created, on my webpage.

Here's the code I use to load the image

```
@GetMapping(
        value="/download",
        produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE
        )
public @ResponseBody byte[] getDownload() throws IOException{
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/static/images/collage.jpeg");

    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

Here's how I create the collage.jpeg file

```
        // delete previous file
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/static/images/collage.jpeg");

        if(file.exists())
            file.delete();


        // Write the collage to a the desired file.
        ImageIO.write(collage, "jpeg", file);
```

The issue I'm having is that when I access the /download endpoint it's retrieving the most previous version of collage.jpeg and not the most recently created one. collage is a BufferedImage object which I use ImageIO to write to the directory.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to clean and  repackage the project? (given you are using maven)

Comment: *FYI:* Files below `src` should not be updated by code. They are *source files*, and will be **read-only** when the code is built and packaged (jar, war, ear, ...).

Comment: @Jalil.Jarjanazy Yes I have, still have the same issue unfortunately

Comment: @Andreas What do you suggest? Should I try uploading to a folder outside of source?

Comment: The `src` directory isn't there at runtime. Resources are loaded from the CLASSPATH, not the source directory. What you are attempting doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SeanG Yes, or to a database. Depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I can try out the database route that sounds smart. I'm essentially trying to create an image and have the user click a button to download the image. Thank you for your help.